# How do I delete some elements of a vector depending on some value of the element?

Tags: rust

I got this working iterating once to get the indices of elements to be deleted and then delete the elements later on, but is there a better way to do this? Maybe in a more functional style?

My working code:

```
let mut tmpv = vec![];
for (index, e) in self.enms.iter().enumerate() {
    if e.x < 0.0 {
        tmpv.push(index);
    }
}
for i in tmpv {
    self.enms.swap_remove(i);
}
```

Comment: You may be interested in [Iterator::filter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter).

Comment: [Working, you say?](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=23b32d6af42677b0d8a65a1508d00409&version=stable)

Comment: To replace your code (minus the bug), the duplicate suggests simply `self.enms.retain(|e| e.x >= 0.0)`.